# specify the same key file in visual studio

Tags: .net, vb.net, obfuscation, crypto-obfuscator

i faced problem while obfuscation process.
i am still beginner don't know how to fix that.

i search on metroframwork ui .dll key file, but not much positive result.`

otherwise i didn't find anything in project file. will grateful for your help as well.

> required key file, i don't have it.

[image: error image]

even if i disable Tamper Detection settings, it have same error.

source code, very simple :

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MsgBox("Welcome")
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you has to skip obfuscation of any assembly whose key is unavailable because you need to resign obfuscated dll using that key.

In general it's uncommon to obfuscate 3rd party dlls.

But in this case the dll is open sourced and its key [is available on github](https://github.com/thielj/MetroFramework/blob/master/MetroFramework.snk).